# Error while configuring openldap with ssl

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap

I have a certificate from Digicert and I have added the keys to the bdb config file. The rest of the LDAP setup works fine except the SSL part. I have added a Mozilla certificate store as well, but i keep getting this error.

> TLS: error: connect - force handshake failure: errno 0 - moznss error -5938 TLS: can't connect: TLS error -5938:Encountered end of file. –

Answer (score 0):

Check your TLS_CACERTDIR to make sure it is pointing to the correct store.

I can't tell from the syntax you posted if you are using it, but for troubleshooting cert\TLS stuff I always use ldapsearch in verbose mode...

ldapsearch -H ldaps://my.ldap.server:636 -v -D "cn=user,ou=unit,o=org" -x -W